# How to send SOAP request in Jmeter

Tags: soap, jmeter, performance-testing

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

i recorded my test using Jmeter Recorder,one of my http request sending SOAP request in Body part.its working gr8

as i can see,in this request there are some KEY VALUE pair.but this will change with each user..
How can i make it dynamic.

I want to feed them as fetched from previous response(extracted from Regular Expression Extractor)

```
eg "where" in SOAP should be from RegEx_where
```

[image: screenshot]

Please Help ..Jmeter is completely new for me.

Accept my apologies if it sounds a stupid question for Jmeter PROs

Comment: Use `${RegEx_where}`

Comment: is it valid in SOAP request...stupid me.. Thnks user7294900  i will chk and get bk to u